# Cannot get package name of Google Chrome on Android

Tags: android

I tried to get Google Chrome's package name by using the following code, but it returned "android", even though I set my default browser is Google Chrome.

```
if (!(isPackageStatus("com.android.chrome") || isPackageStatus("org.mozilla.firefox"))) {
            return false
        }
        val browserIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"))
        val resolveInfo: ResolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(browserIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
        // This is the default browser's packageName
        val packageName: String = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
```

Can anyone help me?

I want it to return "com.android.chrome"